# Best Javascript framework to build SPA with custom template

Tags: javascript, templates, user-interface, frontend

I am searching for a open source javascript framework to use in my web project. I want to build a single page application with the template like you see in the image.

The panel in center will be a dynamic tab and for every menu click, a new tab will be opened in dynamic tab. I had use ExtJS but the license is expensive. My ideia is to use a framework to help me about tab panels, accordion panels, expand/collapse panels.

[image]

What are the best frameworks to use templates in front end??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the goal you are trying to accomplish you should look for so called MV* JavaScript frameworks, they are becoming very popular nowadays and there is quite a few to choose from. Check out this site http://todomvc.com/ to find the one you like.

Please note, that you don't necessarily have to use any framework at all, just the JavaScript library like jQuery or Zepto will do the job unless your project is big and complicated.

If it is, my recomendation is going for AngularJS as it seems to be the most popular front-end JS framework out there and there is a lot of resources on the web to help you get started. It is quite tricky to understand, but once you get over it it is actually quite friendly. Documantain is good, there are some good interactive video tutorials on the official website - make sure to check it out: https://angularjs.org/. It does have a nice templating system that allows you to split your page into pieces and load only the content that you want wrapped in a templated written in a separate html file. Plus - it is being developed by Google.

Also, please note that so called Single Page Applications are [not so SEO friendly](http://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2358775/seo-strategies-for-javascript-heavy-single-page-applications-or-ajax-sites) as regular websites.